# Can "come along" mean to happen?

Tags: word-usage

My dictionary says that **to come along** means *"to progress or to shape up."* For example:

> How is that project coming along?

I would like to know, is *"to happen or to arise"* a valid meaning as well? As in:

> How did this issue/problem come along?

Comment: I haven't heard 'come along', but 'come about' is used in this way.

Answer (score 4):

To **[Come Along](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/come+along)** means :

> 1. To make advances to a goal; progress: *Things are coming along fine.*
> 2. To go with someone else who takes the lead: *I'll come along on the hike.*
> 3. To show up; appear: *Don't take the first offer that comes along.*

So your question can be meaningful, according to the third meaning. You can probably use *come along* in the following way:

> How did this issue/problem come along?

which would mean *how did this issue show up/appear to you?*

However you can consider substituting *come about* in place of *come along* to mean what you are genuinely trying to imply i.e.

> How did this issue/problem come about?

which would mean *how did this issue happen to you?*.

Comment: I think *come about* might be the better idiom here; it's even listed at the page where you link to, and its meaning is *"To take place; happen."* It's hard to say for sure which phrasing would be more suitable, and it might very well depend on the nature of the issue or problem.

Comment: @J.R., Added _come about_ to make it more handy to the OP.

Comment: ...and more handy to everyone else.

Comment: @Mistu4u, it is not correct to say that 'come along' and 'come about' have the same meaning.  They do not.  As J.R. and mcalex have pointed out, 'come along' does not mean 'show up/appear to you'; of these two choices, only 'come about' does. Please consider amending your answer.

Comment: @ShawnMooney, I have never said they save the same meaning. I said _come along_ does not mean which the OP thinks it does i.e. _to happen_ and then I said that using _come along_ in this context can mean _to show up/appear_. Then to make the answer complete and handy for the OP, like J.R. commented, I added the meaning of _come about_ i.e. _to happen_, but I never implied they have the same meaning.

Comment: @Shawn: There's a quoted dictionary definition that says _come along_ means "to show up; appear." I never said that _come about_ was the "only" correct option; in fact, I said that it would depend on the issue/problem. For example, I could imagine myself saying, _"I've been working at this new job for six months, and I'm really liking it, but then the recession comes along, and, the next thing I know, I'm unemployed again!"_ I think "comes along" fits better than "comes about" in that sentence – particularly if the recession isn't over yet.